# How to search within an array thats within struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm having trouble with understanding memory allocation.

For instance if I have a struct as follows:

```
struct AccountInfo{
     int number;
     int balance;
     int past[9];
     int minimum_past;
     int maximum_past;
};
```

How would I access the array `past[9]`? A more direct question would be how I would find the minimum and maximum of `past` and then assign those values to `minimum_past` and `maximum_past`?

I understand to set members in the struct to certain values I could just do something like `AccountInfo -> number = 10;` but with arrays I'm still confused.

Comment: past[12]?? past[9] is defined. Also, AcccountInfo->number is not valid. You will have to make a struct pointer for that. Otherwise you can make a struct variable say acc and use acc.number. Similarly , acc.past[i] gives you ith element of the past array.

Comment: How come past[12]? Isn't it's max size index 8? pass[9]'s max index is past[8].

Comment: `AccountInfo info; /* set up its values */; int* min = std::min_element(std::begin(info.past), std::end(info.past));` (likewise using `std::max_element()`).

Comment: Oops that was a typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a simple example.

define you struct in header file:

```
struct AccountInfo{
     int number;
     int balance;
     int past[9];
     int minimum_past;
     int maximum_past;
};
```

in your cpp file:

```
AccountInfo st_AccInfo;
```

access to your struct:

```
int x = st_AccInfo.number;

for(int i=0; i<sizeof(st_AccInfo.past); i++)
{
   // Navigate your Array from index 0 to 8
}
```

Comment: can `i<sizeof(st_AccInfo.past)` be replaced with `i<9` in this case since the size of the array was already initialized?

Comment: @digggzz yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you declare `past` as an array of 9 integers, as as C++ count indexes from 0, the greater index you can use without invoking undefined behaviour is 8.

That being said, you use array elements exactly like other struct elements:

```
AccountInfo accountInfo;   // create a struct
AccountInfo* paccountInfo = &accountInfo;  // define a pointer to it

accountInfo.last[8] = 12;  // direct access
cout << paccountInfo->last[8] << endl;    // access through pointer - outputs 12
```